# Proposed change in commitment functionality

Tags: feature-request, area-51, commitment-phase

**Commit without committing**

For some Area51 proposals, I'd really like to participate in the private beta, but, at the same time, I have no idea whether I'll be able to answer (m)any questions - I have a fair bit of knowledge on the topic, but the nature of the questions may be outside my knowledge, it really just depends on the questions.

I'm sure many other users are in a similar situation - some commit and some don't, so we end up with:

- Possibly good contributors who didn't commit
- Non-contributors who did commit, raising the number of commits beyond what it should be

Both of the above can contribute to a site failing.

**Separate experts and learners in commitment numbers**

The above is my main concern, but it would also help to be able to differentiate expert (those answering questions) and learners (those asking questions).

Not much needs to be said here:

- A site with mainly learners will end up with many unanswered questions
- A site with mainly experts will end up with very few questions

**Proposal**

In line with the above, I propose we change the commitment dialog box to give the following options:
(it doesn't have to be exactly like this, this is just a starting point)

- Expert (will answer at least 10 questions)
- Learner (will ask at least 10 questions)
- Hybrid (will both ask and answer at least 10 questions)
- Just curious

From here we change the commitment percentage to be the minimum of the following 3 items:

- Number of committers total (200?)
- Number of experts / hybrids (50?)
- Number of learners / hybrids (50?)

**Minor-change proposal**

If the above is declined, could we just include an option to allow users to specify that they're ... well ... sort of just curious (perhaps we can just use the "Just Curious" option) and, most importantly, have this not contribute to the total number of contributors.

And perhaps lower the total number of contributors required, as many successful sites may have had many who were just curious.

Comment: Yes yes yes yes! It can't hurt a site to go to beta with a bunch of curious users in addition to the 'committed-committed' users, and sometimes I want to be there for the beginning of a site without it showing a Black Mark Of Non-Participation on my profile.

Comment: `A site with mainly experts will end up with very few questions`... I've only participated in 1 beta, but we had a fair bit of experts and yet we managed to generate a lot of quality questions based on the idea that we were seeding the side with questions that we already knew the answer too.  Is the issue you are trying to address really a problem in other private betas?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I don't know. Do we really ever know why sites fail? (We can probably run some analysis on which option was selected for users of failed beta's to see if any pattern emerge to see if this would be useful, but I don't have access to this information as far as I know) But, as noted in my question, "Commit without committing" is my main issue.

Comment: @psubsee2003 If you are planning to answer your own questions, you can just select "Hybrid". Not all experts are able to come up with good questions (while they may be able to answer them).

Comment: @Dukeling absolutely, wasn't worried about myself, I was more wondering if this is really an issue that needs fixed.